What did Osama bin Laden's son Omar post on social media?
Osama bin Laden's son was banned from France for making terrorism-related posts that he claims were made by a hacker:

French authorities have ordered Omar bin Laden, a son of slain Al
Qaeda leader Osama bin Laden, to leave the country over posts on
social media, France's interior minister announced on Tuesday. Born in
Saudi Arabia, where he spent his early years, Omar bin Laden, 43, has
also lived in Sudan and Afghanistan. He left his father at the age of
19 and eventually settled in Normandy in northern France in 2016,
taking up painting. FRANCE 24's Vedika Bahl reports.

What did he post exactly?

Le Monde:

On the anniversary of Osama bin Laden's death in May 2023, comments that French officials say glorified "terrorism and al Qaeda" were published on social media in the name of Omar bin Laden, on an account that has now been suspended.
While Omar bin Laden denied being the author of the "reprehensible comments" he did not delete or condemn them, the prefecture said.  He was ordered to leave France on October 27, 2023 and did so "voluntarily." He appealed the decision but a French court upheld the ruling last week.

Euronews:

According to local newspaper Le Publicateur Libre, a controversial tweet was posted by bin Laden on 2 May 2023, the date of his father's birthday.
The post from the now-deleted account @omarbinladin1 read: “History is written only with the blood of these people — to tell the story of these martyrs who made history, built nations and brought glory. Their blood is the lifeline of our faith until judgment day. Rest in peace."
Investigative journalists questioned bin Laden about the matter in an award-winning podcast, "Hechos Reales," or True Facts.
"A person from another country managed to get the password of my Twitter account and posted a Tweet using my name. They were not my words. I reported the Tweet to Twitter and after a week or so, the account was thankfully blocked," bin Laden said.
"I no longer have access to my Twitter account," he added, "so I was unable to remove it myself. I want to tell people I condemn terrorism and violence with all my heart", he added.

Without looking at the court proceedings (on his appeal) it's unclear though if that was all there was to the basis of his ban.

Back in July of last year, authorities staged an intervention in Omar bin Laden's home, as well as in another location in the medieval town of Domfront, according to local outlets.
At the time, an anonymous source involved in the investigation said that "Omar bin Laden was put under investigation for glorifying terrorism but was released once this process was completed."

Perhaps they found more questionable materials, not enough for a prosecution, but perhaps enough for a ban. In some of his earlier interviews he said some things that one might say were attempting to partly excuse or whitewash his father's actions:

In a 2008 interview with ABC News, he said, "my father is very kind man... and he was very sorry when he did something like 11 September."
"He believed if he brought two buildings down, maybe some people, few would die... But millions other would (be) save(d). He believed that", Omar added.
Omar bin Laden went on to assert that he did not agree with his father's actions "I believe what he did was wrong."


Unfortunately the context is unclear. Who are "these" people he mentions and how do we know what he was talking about? Was the date he posted this on relevant, like on bin ladens birthday or something like that?

@user1721135 It says it was posted on Osama bin Laden's birthday. Presumably "these" means people like him.
